# Pyqt5: How to setImage in Qlabel if the string in the file is True

Tags: pyqt5, readfile, qlabel

Can someone tell me what approach or what logic I can do to setImage in a QLabel? I'm using .setPixmap. I'm making a simple GUI that the image in the Qlabel will change depending in the string in the file.

This is my sample code:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(508, 338)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 491, 291))
    self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
    self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 241))
    self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    self.label.setText("")
    self.label.setScaledContents(True)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
    self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_2)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 241))
    self.label_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    self.label_2.setText("")
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
    self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.tab_3)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 461, 241))
    self.label_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    self.label_3.setText("")
    self.label_3.setScaledContents(True)
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    def setImage(self):
    file = open("course","r")
    course = str(file.readlines())
    if course == "Archi":
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ME.jpg"))
```

[image: Qlabel Where the image will show]

[image]

The condition is true, what approach should I do to show the image in the Qlabel whenever i run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setpixmap` is correct. It will set the image to the label.

The problem is with your python code.
`file.readlines()` returns a `list`. so your `if` statement is failing.

In your code, you are comparing `['Archi']` with `"Archi"`, which is false.

Modify it `file.readline()` , which returns a `string` and that should work fine with `if` statement.

And ensure `setImage` function is indented properly.

Comment: what code should I used to connect it in the Qlabel, because the image is not still showing in the Qlabel?

Comment: setPixmap should work fine. First try with some print statements to ensure your if condition is working. Then try with hardcoding the complete image path, and see if your image is displaying.